# How turn off this selection style in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

As you see the screen below, I don't know how to disable it.

Basically, when I highlights any code the cursor become "fat" and I cannot write inside it anymore until I click outside the highlighted code and type the "a" key on my keyboard.

Cursor "fat":

[image]

[image]

Version:

> WebStorm 2019.2 Build #WS-192.5728.87, built on July 22, 2019

Comment: Could you write here you WebStorm version and snippet of your config?

Comment: @AlbertoPerez yes I'm going to update my question

Comment: @AlbertoPerez where I can find my configuration snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be using [IdeaVim](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/164-ideavim) plugin... "Fat" cursor likely indicates that the editor is in command mode that doesn't allow entering text.

If you are not experienced with VIM, I'd suggest disabling/uninstalling the plugin in **Settings | Plugins**

Answer (score 0):

This is normally the way that WebStorm works, if you highlight something it means that you want to edit the whole block of code (copy, cut or paste) and also WebStorm tries to suggest some improvements for the code (The lightbulb). As far as I know, there's no option to change the default behavior when selecting a block of code, but you can check [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Toggling_Case.html).

Comment: Thanks anyway bro